# How to get params in url , and it is array? yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have url like this

```
 http://localhost/belajar4/web/index.php?r=data%2Fsingle&id=2&DataSearch[TANGGAL]=2015-08-04&DataSearch[TANGGAL_SELESAI]=2015-08-12
```

And I want to get DataSearch['Tanggal'] dan DataSearch[TANGGAL_SELESAI]

I have tried for id with

```
 Yii::$app->request->queryParams['id']
```

And it was success for it, but not with DataSearch['Tanggal']

When I try for DataSearch['Tanggal'] the error is

```
 Undefined index: DataSearch[TANGGAL]
```

I think it should have easy to answer but i am newbie for yii2 and i didnt find the solution yet

Comment: what about `Yii::$app->request->queryParams['DataSearch']`

Comment: oh ya thats work, i got the array. but what i need is the string DataSearch['TANGGAL']  and DataSearch['TANGGAL_SELESAI'] separated.

Comment: <prem> array(2) {
  ["TANGGAL"]=>
  string(10) "2015-08-04"
  ["TANGGAL_SELESAI"]=>
  string(10) "2015-08-12"
} </prem>

Comment: it is just array. So you can access it as each other array. See my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get them from array like this:

```
Yii::$app->request->queryParams['DataSearch']["TANGGAL_SELESAI"]
Yii::$app->request->queryParams['DataSearch']["TANGGAL"]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use combination of `ArrayHelper::getValue()` and `Yii::$app->request->get()` with dot notation:

```
use Yii;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;


...

$value = ArrayHelper::getValue(Yii::$app->request->get(), 'DataSearch.TANGGAL_SELESAI');
```

The main advandage is you can avoid `Undefined index` exception and change default value (third parameter).

**Official docs:**

- [Getting values](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-array.html#getting-values)
- [ArrayHelper::getValue()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basearrayhelper.html#getValue%28%29-detail)
- [Yii::$app->request->get()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-request.html#get%28%29-detail)

Answer (score -1):

I had faced slimier issue & spent lots of time to get the value but somehow I found solution like below.

// Trying to print the value

```
echo Yii::$app->request->queryParams['DataSearch']['"TANGGAL_SELESAI"'];

echo Yii::$app->request->queryParams['DataSearch']['"TANGGAL"'];
```